# Sanitize/sanity-check user-supplied content with const_get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action in a Rails application in which I am taking in a "type" for a polymorphic association and looking up a class (`DokiCore` is the name of my engine):

```
def complete
  model_class = DokiCore.const_get(complete_params[:pointer_type])
  pointer = model_class.find(complete_params[:pointer_id])
end

def complete_params
  params.require(:progress).permit(
    :pointer_id,
    :pointer_type
  )
end
```

I'm concerned that a user could supply a random class with "pointer_type" and try to look up other classes in the engine namespace. Is this a worry at all? Is there a Rails-y type way of looking up models *only* by name or should I add a method that tests the value of pointer_type for all models I want to allow in the polymorphic association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like `DokiCore.const_get('::User')` will return top-most `User` class even if there is `DokiCore::User`.

Just add some white-list checking against your user-param and you'll be fine:

```
raise 'Invalid class!' unless ['GoodClass'].include? complete_params[:pointer_type]
```